# Implementing the "." word from Forth in x86 assembly

Tags: macos, printf, x86-64, memory-alignment, forth

I am trying to make a function that, prints a number out on screen. Eventually, I'll make it able to take the top stack item, print it, and then pop it (like the "." word in Forth). But for now, I am trying to keep it simple. I think that I need to align the call stack in some way - and I figured that pushing and popping an arbitrary register before and after calling printf (rbx) would do the trick - but I am still getting a segmentation fault. A backtrace in GDB hasn't helped me make any progress either. Does anyone know why this code is causing a segmentation fault, and how to fix it?

How I am assembling (GAS):
`gcc -masm=intel`

```
.data
    format_num: .ascii "%d\0"

.text
    .global _main
    .extern _printf

print_num:
    push rbx
    lea rdi, format_num[RIP]
    mov esi, 250
    xor eax, eax
    call _printf
    pop rbx
    ret

_main:
    call print_num

    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    syscall
```

Comment: In `_main`, you didn't align the stack before calling `print_num`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm new to assembly, how would I do that?

Comment: The same way as you did in `print_num`: push an arbitrary register.

Comment: You can keep track by mentally stepping through the code.  On entry to any function called by proper ABI-compliant code, the stack pointer will be an odd multiple of 8.  You need to ensure the same is true of any C function you call, which means `rsp` must be an *even* multiple of 8 the instant before you execute `call`.  Every `push, pop, call, ret` adds or subtracts 8 and so flips you between even and odd.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then show us the backtrace.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Or tailcall printf with `jmp _printf` instead of push/call/pop/ret.  Then you enter `_printf` with a valid stack layout, exactly the same one your function got on entry.  (If the OP wants to use the callstack as a Forth stack, they might want to forgo stack alignment except for the rare times they want to make library function calls, and then save RSP by making RBP a frame pointer / `and rsp, -16` / `call` / `leave` / `ret`.)

Comment: @PeterCordes that worked. My other problem now is getting the top value on the stack into esi. How could this be made possible? I'm just wondering since you can't do `pop *32-bit-register*` and anyways, popping when in a function call is probably pretty risky.

Comment: If you really want to use the x86 stack as your Forth stack, `pop rcx` (grab the return address), `pop rsi` (which gets the low 32 bits into ESI) / `push rcx` (put the return address back, higher up on the stack).  So when you eventually return, you've removed a value from the stack.

Comment: Or a more sane thing would have to have the caller pass the top-of-stack value in a register.  Or 2 values if the function takes 2 args.  (Then you can optimize away actually pushing and popping the return value in between feeding it to another function, if that next function consumes the top-of-stack.   e.g. [Are these the smallest possible x86 macros for these stack operations?](//stackoverflow.com/q/62542955)). Just leave the stack manipulation to the caller.  And for most operations, you don't need to call a function, just inline one `add` or `pop`/`add` or something to add the top 2 items

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you mean that I should put those three instructions before I call `print_num` via `jmp`, after, or somewhere within `print_num`?

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't understand what you mean

Comment: No, this version of `print_num` doesn't have any inputs passed anywhere by the caller, so it wouldn't make sense for it to read a value from the stack or a register.  I was talking about in your other questions with real asm "compiled" from Forth where you want to print a value from the stack, or passed by your caller in a register.  If you think through exactly what those instructions do, you should be able to figure out where to put them that would make sense.

Comment: @PeterCordes I figured out a different way - I could use rsi to pop from the stack - and since this was also a source register printf accepted it